# At what conditions a matrix can be transformed in a phase-variable form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given a matrix $A$:
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
-5 & 1 & 0\\ 0 &-2 &1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
At which conditions one can transform $A$ in phase-variable form shown below:
$$
P=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 &0 &1 \\ a_0 & a_1 & a_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $a_0,a_1,a_2$ are constant determined to carry out the transformation.

Comment: you need to precise what you mean by "transform". Do you want to know if there exist invertible matrices $U,V$ such that $UAV=P$ ? or an invertible matrix such that $UAU^{-1}=P$ ? or an invertible matrix $U$ such that $U^t AU=P$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to know if there is an invertible matrix $U$ such that 
$UAU^{-1}=P$, computing characteristic polynomials shows that $(X+5)(X+2)(X+1)=X^3+8X^2+17X+10=X^3-a_2X-a_1X-a_0$, hence if $U$ exists, then $a_0=-10,a_1=-17,a_2=-8$.

Then, both $A$ and $P$ have the same characteristic polynomial with simple roots $-5,-2,-1$, so they are both diagonalisable, and similar to $D=\pmatrix{-5 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & -2 &0 \cr 0 & 0 & -1 }$. Therefore, one can compute using standard methods two invertible matrices $Q,R$ such that $Q^{-1}AQ=D=R^{-1}P R$. Setting $U=RQ^{-1}$ gives $UAU^{-1}=P$.